# Adding a string to the end of every line in a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, append

I have a CSV File with a list of file names with no file extension. I have all the names as strings and would like to add a string .JPG to each line.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#Adding .JPG string to the end of each line for the Part Numbers
string_to_add = ".JPG"

#Open the file and join the .JPG to the current lines
with open("PartNums.csv", 'r') as f:
file_lines = [#Adding String goes here]

#Writes to the file until its done
with open("PartNums.csv", 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(file_lines)
```

I think I need to use the `.join` function however I am not sure how to.

This is what the CSV file looks like now:

```
filename
filename
filename
filename
filename
filename
```

The output I am looking for is:

```
filename.JPG
filename.JPG 
filename.JPG
filename.JPG
filename.JPG
filename.JPG
```

I appreciate all and any help given, Thank you.

Comment: No, I would just like to add a string to a string from a CSV file. is there anyway I could do that?

Comment: JPG (assuming you refer to image format) is **not** a string.

Comment: I dont need it as a file extension Id like to add it as a string. I will be compare it to another list of string that look the same but have .JPG at the end so I need them to look the same

Answer (score 1):

Okay, your question is a bit messy, but from your code, it seems like you have your filenames as a dataframe before you print it to csv. So if you would like to add'.JPG' to each filename it could be done before saving to csv and look something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['X00TB0001',
    'X01BJ0003',
    'X01BJ0004',
    'X01BJ0005',
    'X01BJ0006'], columns = ['jpgs'])
df['jpg_ext'] = df['jpgs'] + '.JPG'
df
```

just made it an extra column for clarity :)